# Selenium not finding elements in Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, web

I'm trying to search for a WebElement using Selenium's API. I tried using a wildcard to obtain all the elements on the page and then looped through them and it's still not being printed. Is there a way they can be hidden? I can't simply search for the id or name because it's always a different id.

This is an example of what I'm trying to retrieve:

```
<div class="question-body open-ended-single">
<input aria-labelledby="question-title-661489021" id="661489021" aria-required="false" data-sm-open-single="true" class="wds-input wds-input--lg qt-input_text text" name="661489021" size="50" value="">
</div>
```

Here are some examples of code I've tested:

```
        List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div"));
        System.out.println(sectionList.size());

        for (WebElement ele : sectionList) {
            System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));
        }
```

Also replaced //div with //input, etc. The list has a size of 25+ so does retrieve elements, just not the one I need.

```
        List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'open-ended-single')]"));
        List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.cssName("*"));
```

EDIT: Issue is solved. Thanks for everyone's help. The issue turned out to be with my HtmlUnitDriver so switched over to chrome headless and works perfectly.

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page and clarify what exactly are your trying to get?

Comment: what does it print `System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));` ?

Comment: and what is the `List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'open-ended-single')]"));` size of this list ?

Comment: I print that line to make sure I have the correct element

Comment: The list has a size of 24+, so it does retrieve elements, just not the one in the post. Also edited the code to make it more clear of the element I'm trying to retrieve

Comment: what are you trying to retrieve from the list of webelements?

Comment: @itronic1990 It's a textbox, but isn't being returned at all

Answer (score 0):

try with `cssSelector` :

```
List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class$='open-ended-single'] input[aria-labelledby^='question-title-']"));
        System.out.println(sectionList.size());

        for (WebElement ele : sectionList) {
            System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));
        }
```

Comment: List size is 0 with this code, also tried with this:

`List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[aria-labelledby^='question-title-']"));`

Comment: Is that element in viewport ?

Comment: Can you share a image of that ?

Comment: Can we have to URL also ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='question-body open-ended-single']"));
System.out.println("List Size is " + elems.size());
        for(WebElement e: elems ) {
            String idValue= e.findElement(By.xpath(".//input")).getAttribute("id");
            System.out.println(idValue);
        }
```

Output:

```java
List Size is 1
661489021
```

Comment: This returns a list size of 0

`List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='question-body open-ended-single']"));`

Comment: can you show the divs you are trying to get as list? class name for all the divs is the same?

Comment: Running my code is giving me list size as 1 and getAttribute("id") as 661489021. Dont know why you are getting list size as 0

Comment: Why would yours be a different output? Could it be because of my setup or drivers? Seems weird because it does return all of the elements except this one.

Comment: I used your findElements() statement : List<WebElement> sectionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'open-ended-single')]")); and the size() is returning 1. Are we missing something or you looking at a different url?

Answer (score 0):

This xpath would potentially work:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'question-body')]//input
```

You may alos need to use an explicit wait for the element to appear before trying to find it.

Comment: Having the same issue, and already have a delay implemented

Comment: I think your question may be unclear. How do you know it's not returning the webElement you need?  Which one ARE you trying to retrieve and how do you know it's not the right one?